# How to get the path of an SVG to fill the entire image?

Tags: css, svg

I'm using an inline SVG from FontAwesome. The image itself works fine, but for some reason that I can't quite understand the path element is not filling the SVG - the SVG tag itself seems to have padding around it.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/xhsypfub/3/

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 512" width="75px" height="75px"><path d="M31.7 239l136-136c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L127.9 256l96.4 96.4c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L201.7 409c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-136-136c-9.5-9.4-9.5-24.6-.1-34z"/></svg>`

How do I get the path element to fill the entire SVG? (And why does that not happen by default?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="76 96 128 322" width="56px" height="75px"><path d="M31.7 239l136-136c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L127.9 256l96.4 96.4c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9L201.7 409c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-136-136c-9.5-9.4-9.5-24.6-.1-34z"/></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this is closer to what you want. Use the view box and width/height properties to "crop" the image (You'll probably have to edit the above properties to get it exactly how you want it, but this is a start). I would assume this isn't the default behavior so that there is a natural margin to the icon and it wouldn't sit up against surrounding text.

Comment: This is great, thanks Adam. How did you figure this out?

Comment: Lots of youtube

Comment: Hah, ok. Thanks again